# JSP with OOP? Is it possible?

Tags: java, jsp, oop

I started studying JSP about 2 days ago and developed simple programs with it but I come up with an idea of using OOP concepts into JSP but it doesn't work. Is it possible or not. I've created 2 jsp files and 1 class of getters and setters in my Web Project.

This is  HumanJaySP file.

[image]

This is the HumanJayEsPOutput file.

[image]

The Human.class contains getters and setters of String variable firstname,lastname,address, and gender

When I run the program and send the data inside the human object. This error pops up.

[image]

Is there a way to make this work or is OOP really not usable in JSP?

Comment: Don't include *screenshots* of code. Include code. Readable, selectable, copiable, searchable code.

Comment: Don't see any import of `Human` class in `HumanJayEsPOutput` file. Like `<%@ page import ..`

Answer (score 1):

It is possible, you should only import your files, classes etc.

```
<%@ page import="com.servlet.java.*"%>
```

Comment: Yes it is possible... But you should at least say OP that he'd better use JSP and JSTL instead of scriptlets